# including a jquery on click countdown on mulitple pages

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, countdown

i am having problems including a jquery on click countdown. The script is included in multiple pages. It does work sometimes but not every time.

Something like this:
Quiz Questionpage countdown => oncomplete to Answerpage => Questionpage with countdown =>on complete to countdown. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.countdown360.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var countdown = $("#countdown").countdown360({
    radius: 60,
    seconds: 10,
    label: ['Sekunde', 'Sekunden'],
    fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    strokeStyle: "#f7a600",
    fillStyle: "#203a8f",
    autostart: false,
    onComplete: function () {window.location = '1-2-3_S1_0001_a.php';  
    }
});

document.getElementById('clickcountdown').addEventListener('clickcountdown', function() {
        countdown.start();
            }, false);
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $("#notready").delay(5000).hide(200);
});
</script>
```

The delay at the end is because i thought DOM isn't ready, but it didn't help.
I already tried document ready function too, didn't help either. Next try was to use different ID's for each page because of the DOM's cache. Didn't work.

The link "clickcountdown" looks something like this:

```
<div id="navi">
  <p id="clickcountdown"><a href="1-2-3_S1_0001_f.php?Befehl=gewinn2">Start<span>›</span></p>
</div>
```

Someone got a idea why it isn't working every time?

**Edit:** I have tried to get output from document.getElementByID though adding console.log('test'); after countdown start. But it didn't left any traces in console.

Many thanks in advance,
Boris

Comment: Define "not working".  When you debug, specifically how does it fail?  Is one of the selectors not finding what you expect it to find?  Is there an error in the JavaScript console?  Where is this `#notready` element?  What does it have to do with the countdown?

Comment: Thats the strange thing it doesn't show any failures in the console. The #notready was just a overlay to prevent click on "clickcountdown" for 5 seconds. As said sometimes it works like a charm and by my feeling... if i am clicking to fast on "clickcountdown" the countdown won't appear and just the link is followed.